# Python - Filter and Lambda Beginner Question

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, lambda

I'm learning Python through Colt Steele Modern Python Bootcamp.
I'm now on filter section and I'm having trouble understanding this or I guess I have a trouble understanding lists and dictionaries.

In video it shows a list of dictionaries

```
users = [
{"username":"samuel", "tweets": ["blabla"]},
{"username":"test", "tweets": []}
]
```

Then he goes to separate inactive users, the ones with empty key tweets by:

```
inactive_users = list(filter(lambda u:len(u["tweets"]) == 0, users)
```

This works of course, however just for the sake of learning, I tried to apply it with a for loop but I'm unsuccessful.

Because this is what I was trying to do

```
users = [
    {"username": "samuel", "tweets": []},
    {"username":"toni","tweets": ["blabla"]},
    {"username": "tata", "tweets": []},
    {"username":"hHh","tweets": ["abba"]},
    {"username": "SAEl", "tweets": []},
    {"username":"brte","tweets": ["abba"]}
]
inaktiv = []
index = 0
for u in users:
    if len(users[index]["tweets"]) == 0:
        inaktiv.append(u)
        index += 1
print(inaktiv)
```

My question is... How can this be achieved with a for loop because I can't figure it out. I tried different variations of for loop.

All I get is an empty []

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm a little skeptical of the "modern Python" title, because using list/filter/lambda instead of a comprehension seems very old-fashioned to me.

Comment: Do they also teach the list comprehension, i.e., `[u for u in users if not u["tweets"]]`? That might be more trivial to write as loop...

Comment: Just about to mention that.. ;-) really worried the quality of material.

Comment: As to your code attempt, it does not print an empty list when the first one has no tweets (which is the case you presented). The logical problem in your attempt is that `index += 1` should always happen, not only when you have a match. But overall, this is not very pythonic, as you don't need that index at all.

Comment: @KellyBundy thanks for your input, appreciate it. I'll try and practice it a bit with list comp. And he did teach list and dict comp... I'm complete novice with no background. I just thought of for loop since he mentioned filter can be applied to iterable object. For loop is the first thought that popped in my mind. If you guys have better resources to learn on udemy. I'm more than happy to go through them. I'm looking for a career change to backend dev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way would be:

```
inaktiv = []
for u in users:
    if len(u["tweets"]) == 0:
        inaktiv.append(u)
```

If you come, for example, from a C background and you're very used to for cycles with indexes to access array elements, then you will probably find this solution a bit easier to understand (but it's not pythonic, nor the recommended one):

```
inaktiv = []
for index in range(len(users)):
    if len(users[index]["tweets"]) == 0:
        inaktiv.append(users[index])
```

Instead, using a list comprehension would be much better:

```
inaktiv = [u for u in users if len(u["tweets"]) == 0]
```

Also, remember that `len(u["tweets"]) == 0` has the same effect (in this case) as `not u["tweets"]`, so you can shorten the whole code a bit:

```
inaktiv = [u for u in users if not u["tweets"]]
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this. especially for the one you said "not pythonic" it helped me understand. I usually plug it in in Thonny and see how it behaves.
I'll practice list and dictionary comprehension more. And thanks for your patience in explaining how it works.

When you said not pythonic, did you mean it's not good python style guide? If so, is this the one https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/ where I can learn more about it after finishing course and doing some practice projects?

Comment: done, thanks again! Are there some resources you would recommend me to go over while learning or better resources to learn? The goal for me is to go for back-end development role eventually

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to achieve something like this:

```py
users = [
    {"username": "samuel", "tweets": []},
    {"username":"toni","tweets": ["blabla"]},
    {"username": "tata", "tweets": []},
    {"username":"hHh","tweets": ["abba"]},
    {"username": "SAEl", "tweets": []},
    {"username":"brte","tweets": ["abba"]}
]
inactive = []
for user in users:
    if len(user['tweets']) == 0: # also you can use: if not user['tweets']
        inactive.append(user)
print(inactive)
```

It is worth noting that you were close to the goal. The problem with your code was that you were only incrementing the index if the array was empty. The problem is fixed like this:

```py
users = [
    {"username": "samuel", "tweets": []},
    {"username":"toni","tweets": ["blabla"]},
    {"username": "tata", "tweets": []},
    {"username":"hHh","tweets": ["abba"]},
    {"username": "SAEl", "tweets": []},
    {"username":"brte","tweets": ["abba"]}
]
inaktiv = []
index = 0
for u in users:
    if len(users[index]["tweets"]) == 0:
        inaktiv.append(u)
    index += 1
print(inaktiv)
```

Comment: @Riccardo Bucco thanks guys for your solutions, I feel a bit dumb now looking at these..

Kelly, Sam and Daniel,,yes he teaches list and dict comprehension however I haven't thought of that to be honest. I'm just a beginner with no tech background.

I just thought of for loop since he mentioned that filter can be applied to iterable object and he showed this as an example for filters.

If you guys have some better resources for complete novice to learn Python, I'd be happy to look through them as I'm looking for a career change to backend development.

Comment: I'm not very experienced myself, but I'm familiar with them. They usually advise Mark Lutz. After reading it, if you want to delve deeper into python, Fluent Python is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I detect in your code is that your index increase is under your if condition. This means that if the first person in users is active the index will not increase. So you will have an empty list of inactive people.